# problem with datetime field in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem with datetime attribute in Rails model.

model:

```
attr_accessor :from, :to, :via, :datetime
```

erb template:

```
<%= f.text_field :from %>
<%= f.text_field :to %>
<%= f.text_field :via %>
<%= f.datetime_select :datetime, :discard_year => true %>
```

I got:

`@datetime(4i)' is not allowed as an instance variable name`

On this line: `@search_form = SearchForm.new params[:search_form]`

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what's causing the error, but I can tell you that to fix it, you'll need to change the attribute name `datetime` to, say `sent_on` (most anything else, really).

Why the error?  I'd guess it's because `datetime` is a data type in SQL, and thus shouldn't be used as a column name, but the error seems to be coming from ruby - either your model or ActionView, so I'm not sure if that supports my theory...

Anyway, hope this helps!

**Update:**  I just tested it, and you *can* use "datetime" as a column name in SQL (MySQL, at least).  There goes that theory - it's a Rails thing, then, I guess...